Repeatedly getting UPLOAD_ERR_PARTIAL in PHP
I've a mobile app client (flutter, iOS and Android) from which I'm uploading pictures either picked or taken via device camera to a specific REST API endpoint of content-type multipart/form-data. Test requests doing this, no matter if a single file or multiple files at once are uploaded at the same time, never fail.
When files are uploaded via the app itself, the upload seems to randomly fail due to an UPLOAD_ERR_PARTIAL error in the logs. I've checked the solution if adding the header(Connection: close) HTTP header recommended in multiple sources (e.g. here and here), but the error still happens occasionally.
The Flutter code used to upload the file is:
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:http_parser/http_parser.dart';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';

void main() {
  Future<dynamic> uploadPhoto() async {
    /// Build request route via base URI prefix
    final Uri route = Uri.https(
      "example.org",
      "/namespace/v1/uploads",
    );

    var request = http.MultipartRequest(
      'POST',
      route,
    );

    /// Request Body
    request.fields['upload_id'] = 'whatever';
    request.fields['upload_description'] = 'you want';

    /// For example purposes
    final XFile? imageXFile;

    /// imageXFile is valid and present and not null at this point
    final String imagePath = imageXFile!.path;
    final String imageExtension = imagePath.split('.').last.toLowerCase();
    MediaType mediaType;

    switch (imageExtension) {
      case 'jpg':
      case 'jpeg':
        mediaType = MediaType('image', 'jpeg');
        break;
      case 'png':
        mediaType = MediaType('image', 'png');
        break;
      default:

        /// If the MIME-Type is not one of the allowed ones, interrupt with an
        /// according error message
        throw Exception("Invalid MIME");
    }

    /// Request Files
    request.files.add(
      await http.MultipartFile.fromPath(
        'uploads[]',
        imagePath,

        /// The request occasionally fails without the provision of a filename
        /// and mediaType
        filename: 'upload.$imageExtension',
        contentType: mediaType,
      ),
    );

    await request.send();
  }
}


I've added the php and apache tags as the server receiving the request is an Apache Server running PHP 8.2, without any specific server configs, as this potentially is related to server configs ..?
Current php.ini settings (relevant) :
post_max_size = 25000000
upload_max_filesize = 15000000
max_execution_time = 30
max_input_time = 60

Current apache reqtimeout.conf settings (found relevant due to this):
RequestReadTimeout header=20-40,minrate=500
RequestReadTimeout body=10,minrate=500

Further infos:

I've prepared the endpoint to respond with a specific response if post_max_size is exceeded, so that can't be the reason.
I've prepared the endpoint to respond with a specific response if upload_max_filesize is exceeded, so that's also not the reason.
All uploads of the mobile app fire one upload request per file, hence no request uploads more than one file.
It is possible that up to 10 (single file upload) requests are dispatched within the same second from the same client, but that's the absolute worst-case scenario / not more.

